# Checkbox-lists or individual columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-design, checkboxlist

I am trying to design the web form for the questionnaire below. The questionnaire in total has over 200 questions using drop-downs and check-boxes. I am wondering if I should use checkbox lists and create a many to many relation in the database or just create columns of type bit and map them to every single checkbox.

The form wont change in years so I am not worried about the data changing. In the other hand performance is a very important part of the application.

[image: questionaire]

Comment: if they can only mark one chk box then i would go with a chk bx list.

Comment: That will make the form database heavy and performance will decrease having to load all the checkboxes name/value and selected options since there is a mix of everything. Some you can select only one and some you can select many. Thats kinda my debate, is it really worth it for a form that will not get any additional values and will remain the same for the years to come.